# Space between references, then bibliography not compiling

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I'm new to Latex and haven't been able to figure this out on my own. I'm trying to use Bibtex with authordate format on my in-text citations, but they were always showing up with an abbreviation of the Key instead of the author's name. Also, I was getting a lot of white space between the "References" heading and the beginning of my references, which I don't want and which I was not able to fix by adding negative vspace.

Here's my preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including pictures


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Required for accented characters

\usepackage[round]{natbib} %Bibliography!


\usepackage[font={small}]{caption}

\usepackage[
top    = 3cm,
bottom = 3cm,
left   = 3.00cm,
right  = 3cm]{geometry} %modify all margins

\makeatletter

%\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{\textbf{#1.}} % Change the square brackets for each bibliography item from '[1]' to '1.'

\renewcommand{\@listI}{\itemsep=0pt} % Reduce the space between items in the itemize and enumerate environments and the bibliography

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{ % Customize the title - do not edit title and author name here, see the TITLE block below

\begin{flushright} % Right align

{\LARGE\@title} % Increase the font size of the title

\title{\textbf{Illiteracy in Europe}\\ % Title

Origins and Solutions} % Subtitle

\author{\textsc{Katherine Hardin} % Author

\\{\textit{Die Freie Universit\"at Berlin}}} % Institution

\date{Sommersemester 2015} % Date

\begin{document}

A survey conducted during the report's preparation revealed that 
European Union citizens are generally pessimistic about the power of 
education to improve social mobility ~\cite[17]{lisbon}. Nevertheless,  
education remains a critical component of combatting the problems 
revealed by Rodriguez's report as well as establishing the culture of 
lifelong learning for which the Councile of Europe aims. Not only  is 
education the simplest way to establish contact with almost all 
citizens, but also it plays a crucial role in encouraging democratic 
engagement, fostering social cohesion, and equalizing opportunities for 
individuals' intellectual and vocational growth, three pillars of the 
Council of Europe's current education policy ~\citep{coe}. 

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{LangEdPol}
\end{document}
```

The references were compiling correctly until I started troubleshooting the formatting. Now I've changed everything I can think of back to how it was before, but the document still compiles with no list of references and with question marks in place of the in-text citations. The Bibtex file remains unchanged; Here's the bib information for the first citation in the sample paragraph above:

```
@Book{lisbon,

author = {Rodriguez, Ricardo},

title = {The Lisbon Strategy 2000-2010: An analysis and evaluation of the methods used and results achieved},

publisher = {European Parliament},

year = {2010},

}
```

Now I get errors for each citation that say that the citation is undefined, and/or it says that `paper.aux` couldn't be identified. I've been compiling in latex, then bibtex, then latex, then latex, so that's not the issue. What else can I do to find the problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. At the moment, your document is a fragment only and the `.bib` file is not available to us

Comment: Can you provide as also with the error messages you get, when trying to compile.

Comment: I can find no bibliography style file named `author-date.bst` on the CTAN. I've located files named `authordate1.bst` thru `authordate4.bst`, but none named `author-date.bst`. Do check if you got the name of the bibliography style correct.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am concerned, you want your in text references appear like for example [Einstein, 1905]. This can be achieved by

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
```

A list of possible bibliographystyles can be found at: [Bibiliographystyles](http://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibtex_bibliography_styles)
.